# How do parenthesis affect filters in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I am learning Pandas and while playing around with some filters something came up.

I was using this filter on the classical stackoverflow survay to get only the rows where the applicants had an even Respondent ID AND they were coding as a hobby:

```
filt = df["Hobbyist"] == "Yes" & df["Respondent"] % 2 == 0
```

But then the "Yes" got higlighted by the code editor and I got the following error:

TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [int64] array and scalar of type [bool]

That's when I put parenthesis around the (df["Hobbyist"] == "Yes"), but then, the only filter that was apply was the Respondent one. Even with the & operator.

At the end I added parenthesis for both conditions and it worked fine but I felt curious about the reason why it worked only the Respondent filter.

Comment: The precedence of `&` is too high, certainly higher than `and`.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).

`&` has higher precedence than `==`, thus your initial code is equivalent to:

```
filt = df["Hobbyist"] == ("Yes" & (df["Respondent"] % 2)) == 0
```

You should use:

```
filt = (df["Hobbyist"] == "Yes") & (df["Respondent"] % 2 == 0)
```

Or, to avoid parentheses:

```
filt = df["Hobbyist"].eq("Yes") & df["Respondent"].mod(2).eq(0)
```